# Problem while deploying custom SPI (FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider)

Tags: jboss, keycloak

**Story**

I'm using keycloak 6.0.1. I have one realm with two types of users: Admins and regular users. I need a theme that can distinguish between them since the logins are different (3 fields vs 2 fields). Therefore I want to extend the provider FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider to pass through a custom parameter. I'm using keycloak deployer to deploy my SPIs.

**Problem**

Keycloak unfortunately throws an exception while deployment:

> 09:55:32,170 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"spi-1.0.0.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"spi-1.0.0.jar\"
>      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/theme/FreeMarkerUtil
>      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil from [Module \"deployment.spi-1.0.0.jar\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
>   09:55:32,165 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."spi-1.0.0.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."spi-1.0.0.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "spi-1.0.0.jar"
>       at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
>       at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
>       at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
>       at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
>       at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
>       at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
>       at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
>       at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/theme/FreeMarkerUtil
>       at deployment.spi-1.0.0.jar//com.example.keycloak.spi.CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory.init(CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory.java:23)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.loadFactories(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:217)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.deploy(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:115)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.ProviderManagerRegistry.deploy(ProviderManagerRegistry.java:42)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-server-subsystem@6.0.1//org.keycloak.subsystem.server.extension.KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.deploy(KeycloakProviderDeploymentProcessor.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.as.server@8.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil from [Module "deployment.spi-1.0.0.jar" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
>       ... 14 more

I've also tried the module approach but then I get a NullPointerException:

> 09:23:09,394 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.createAuthenticationSession(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:193)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.process(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:141)
>       at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@6.0.1//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildGet(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:108)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.6.3.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)...

I've been following the official docs. My other custom Pbkdf2PasswordHashProvider actually works just fine. Am I missing something here?

**Source**

```
import org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil;

public class CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider extends FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider {

    public CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider(KeycloakSession session, FreeMarkerUtil freeMarker) {
        super(session, freeMarker);
        setAttribute("isAdmin", uriInfo.getPath().contains("admin"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation with the FreeMarkerAccountProvider/FreeMarkerAccountProviderFactory and was receiving `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/theme/FreeMarkerUtil`.

This solved the problem [Keycloak plugin using keycloak-services](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-November/012410.html).

As I am registring my Provider with the Keycloak Deployer. It seems that it doesn't hadle all the dependencies, so I've created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file with my dependencies under src/main/resources/META-INF. Example here [jboss-deployment-
structure.xml](https://github.com/dteleguin/beercloak/blob/14da8578310f2d257bdc1b059a8d355343174180/src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml).

I also had to disabled the existing Provider and activate mine instead. I did this by adding the following to my standalone.xlm in the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">` tag :

```
<spi name="account">
  <provider name="freemarker" enabled="false"/>
  <provider name="myfreemarker" enabled="true"/>
</spi>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may find a solution for you (I had a similar problem and works for me now), tells me if it's work for you as well.
I think you have a CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory in your code which comes with your CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.

```
public class CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsFactory extends FreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory {

private FreeMarkerUtil freeMarker;

@Override
public LoginFormsProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
    return new CustomFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider(session, freeMarker);
}

@Override
public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    freeMarker = new FreeMarkerUtil();
}

@Override
public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {}

@Override
public void close() {
    freeMarker = null;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "customfreemarker";
}
```

}

Then you need to activate your provider in the standalone-configuration.cli like bellow:

> embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml
>   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login:add()
>   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login/provider=freemarker:add(enabled="false")
>   /subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login/provider=customfreemarker:add(enabled="true")

It seems that you don't need to activate your custom factory for the login provider. I keep the default id "freemarker" and it is taken into consideration instead of the default factory. Only the login provider factory works like this, don't know why.

When i change the function with the same function as original class FreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory like bellow it works (and you don't need lines in standalone.xml any more):

```
@Override
public String getId() {
    return "freemarker";
}
```

I think it is a Keycloak issue/imporvement ?? because it works well with other providers like you said. But i did not find anything about it in keycloak issues. The problem apears between v4.4.0.Final and 4.5.0.Final.
Keep me informed of your progress.

Answer (score 0):

check the modules.xml of your module if it includes

```
<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
```